# Linux: Running only specified application upon boot completion

Tags: linux

My embedded PC is running vanilla 4.9.20 (x64)
Upon boot completion, using /etc/init.d/rcS a C++ application (**my.out**) is running.
SSH, telnet are blocked with iptables.
The root,user accounts have a very strong password.

I want that **only** if **my.out** is properly signed (by me) it will run.
So if an attacker puts his own application (e.g **malware.out**), it will not run.

Is it possible ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Almost certainly this is the wrong approach. The linux kernel already has facilities to restrict things, so no need for you to modify kernel code. I suggest you start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp and see where that takes you.

Comment: Hi icarus. Thank you very much for your reply. I modified my question. Can you please reinspect ?

Comment: So the modified question now becomes a `root of trust` problem. You only want the code to run if it is correctly signed, but how is the system going to know that it is correctly signed? The usual approach is to run a program, but what if that program is tampered with? When you check the signature are you going to use a local file to check against, or a remote service? If the attacker can replace my.out what stops them replacing the signature as well? I suggest you look into DM_VERITY which is the system that keeps millions of chromebooks virus free.